# Is there a canonical way to save an existing site as a template in WebMatrix?

Tags: webmatrix, webmatrix-3

I want to use an existing site that I built in WebMatrix as the starting point for another one. IOW, I want to use it as a template. Is there a "proper" way of doing this, or is it just a matter of "saving as" the existing site to a new folder, and then opening that folder and making the necessary changes?

I could "just try it" and see what happens, but I'd rather avoid that step if somebody knows of a better way to do it if doing so would end up mayhemifying my experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebMatrix site templates are Web Deploy Packages. I've written about how to create one for WebMatrix here: [Creating A Custom Template For WebMatrix](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/169/creating-a-custom-template-for-webmatrix). You can get some more detail on Web Deploy Packages for the IIS site here: http://www.iis.net/learn/develop/windows-web-application-gallery/package-an-application-for-the-windows-web-application-gallery

Comment: Thanks, Mike; coincidentally, I had insomnia last night, and got up and re-read parts of your WebMatrix book - it's a gem!

Comment: I too read parts of my book when I have insomnia. Sends me straight back to the land of ZZzzzzz.